# I want To show Image Popup

Tags: html, image, button, popup

i have a very static landing page. but in this page there's a button when someone clicks it. it should open a popup image , very simple popup image. can this be happen? and what will be the code for html?
please guide

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

[Code from W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal_img)

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded";
  captionText.innerHTML = "StackOverflow";
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
/* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */
#myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (Image) */
.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image (Image Text) - Same Width as the Image */
#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */
.modal-content, #caption {
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform:scale(0)}
  to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="myImg"  style="width:100%;max-width:300px">Click Me</button>


<div id="myModal" class="modal">

 
  <span class="close">&times;</span>

  
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01" src="https://www.debuggr.io/static/3a4bfeeaa7a69e6aa9f4ba6ae4218622/af144/cover.png">

 
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: We can also vote up, when the answer works :)
Do not take downvotes personally. They are given for many reasons. Some are given when ppl do not like the number of indents you give your code and some are given in anger for not being the first to answer. Give SO a chance.